# Stack overflow in recursive function (language C)

Tags: c, function, visual-c++, recursion, stack-overflow

I have a task in which I should to write code for a function which calculates n-element of geometric progression (sequence). The teacher wants to have only one "return" in the end.

```html
int geoprogress (int a, int q, int n)
 {
  int result;
  if (n == 0)
  {
   result = a;
  }
  if (q == 0)
  {
   return;
  }
  if (n == -1)
  {
   result = geoprogress (a, q, n + 1)/q;
  }
  else 
  {
   result = geoprogress (a, q, n - 1)*q;
  }
  return result;
 }


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  int x = 5,
  h = 3,
  p = 1,
  rez;
 const int size = 4;

 for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
 {
 rez = geoprogress (x, h, i);
 }

 return 0;
}
```

But when I write such code I get "Stack overflow". 
Can anybody help me? How can I make a function of n-element of geometric progression using function "return" once in the end of the function body?

Comment: You will get a lot better help if you edit the question to include the code as text in the body of the question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [**About**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the link describing [**How to Ask a Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Providing the necessary details, including your code, and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question. Linking to other information is not sufficient, as that information may change location or no longer be available at any time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must protect against dividing by zero. Specifically, any time the value of `q` may be zero. At a minimum you need to test `q` each time you enter your function. With the additional code you posted, if you insure `q` isn't `0` before calling `geoprogress`, that is sufficient as well. Regardless, a test in `geoprogress` is a solid failsafe:

```
int geoprogress (int a, int q, int n)
{
    int result;
    if (n==0)
    {
        result = a;
    }
    if (q == 0)
    {
        return (value of choice);   /* or just return */
    }
    if (n == -1)
    {
        result = geoprogress (a, q, n + 1)/q;
    }
    else
    {
        result = geoprogress (a, q, n - 1)/q;
    }
    return result;
}
```

You will also need to make sure your function ultimately terminates with `n = 0` or in some other way. This makes `if (n == -1)` look suspicious. What if `n = -2`? The value of `n` becomes progressively more negative and the function may never terminate. Without seeing the remainder of the code it is hard to tell, but it looks like `if (n == -1)` would work better as `if (n < 0)`.

There is also a logic error in the function concerning when/how it terminates. If `n > 0`, your function enters an **endless loop** toggling the value of `n` between `0` and `-1`:

```
result: 0  geoprogress (2, 3, 4)
result: 0  geoprogress (2, 3, 3)
result: 0  geoprogress (2, 3, 2)
result: 0  geoprogress (2, 3, 1)
result: 0  geoprogress (2, 3, 0)  /* non-terminating loop entered */
result: 0  geoprogress (2, 3, -1)
result: 0  geoprogress (2, 3, 0)
result: 0  geoprogress (2, 3, -1)
result: 0  geoprogress (2, 3, 0)
result: 0  geoprogress (2, 3, -1)
(snip)
```

Your test `if (n == 0)` simply sets `result = a` and has no control over function return. Your new value of `result = a` is then immediately overwritten with your next call to `result = geoprogress()`. It looks like you intended:

```
if (n==0)
{
    return a;
}
```

Otherwise, your recursion never terminates because `n` always bounces around between `0` and `-1`, neither of which will terminate the recursion. **Why?** Think about it, look at the following code:

```
if (n == -1)
{
    result = geoprogress (a, q, n + 1)/q;
}
else
{
    result = geoprogress (a, q, n - 1)/q;
}
```

Pick any value for `n`. Now ask yourself **when will this return?** Answer: It won't. You either call `geoprogress` again with `n + 1` or `geoprogress` again with `n - 1`. You never reach `return result` in your function. That is what causes me to believe the logic is probably intended to be `if (n == 0) return a;`. That gives the function a way to return. Either that or one of the other `result =` needs to be a `return`.

A recursive function needs at a minimum two things **(1)** appropriate setup of the values before entering recursion, and **(2)** a way to return from, or terminate, the recursion. There is virtually no setup in your recursive logic. The only thing you are doing is testing `n` and increasing or decreasing `n` by `1`. With that being the only **setup** you provide no way for the recursion to ever terminate as the function is currently written.

Also, you are performing `integer division`. This makes `result = 0` any time `geoprogress (...) < q`. If you are interested in fractional values, you will need to make result a `float` or `double` as well as the type for `geoprogress`. With the values you provide, the answer is always `3` if you terminate with `return a;`E.g.:

```
i: 0  result: 3
i: 1  result: 3
i: 2  result: 3
i: 3  result: 3
```

What are you modeling and what should the values be? I can continue to look at the function in the abstract, but if I knew what you were modeling, that would really help. Is this representative of some equation or some numerical expansion? Recursion is tricky enough when you have a clear model, recursively modeling the unknown is much more difficult.

---

After working through the logic of your code once more, what it looks like is missing is an `else` clause. The recursion works properly as follows (leaving you to prevent `q=0`, and with the integer div issue)

```
int geoprogress (int a, int q, int n)
{
    int result = 0;

    if (n==0)
    {
        result = a;
    }
    else
    {
        if (n == -1)
        {
            result = geoprogress (a, q, n + 1)/q;
        }
        else
        {
            result = geoprogress (a, q, n - 1)/q;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

That is your original code with an additional `else` which was all that was needed to make recursion terminate on `(n == 0)`. Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: Thank you very much. I`ll follow your advice.

Comment: You also have additional logic issues. Hold on and I'll add more.

Comment: I added the second part of the code. Check it out if it will be helpful.

Comment: It did, read through the entire answer, but pay particular attention to the last bit. I believe the missing `else` was your original problem, but you still have the `integer division` to figure out and I would keep the test for `q == 0` in the code just in case someone else uses your function in the future.

Comment: Thanks so much. I guess I was not attentive. I`ll keep the condition with q==0. Thank you again.

Comment: Glad it helped. It was a good exercise. If the answer was helpful, you can select it as solving your issue by checking the checkmark at the top of the answer.